# need some help regarding models association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, models

My scenario is i have  a user model, contact model and profile_url model.

Following is the association b\w user and contact models.

```
user has_many :contacts, :through=> :user_contacts
user has_many :user_contacts

contact has_many :users, :through=>:user_contacts
contact has_many :user_contacts

user_contact belongs_to :user
user_contact belongs_to :contact
```

so far so good. The problem comes when i try to associate these models with the profile_url model. The scenario is whenever a user gets registered on the application it will be assigned a profile url which will be a public profile url. So if i signed up i would have something like http://www.mysite.com/mike.fererra as a public url to my profile. Now when i add you as a contact in my contact list then you will be assigned a private url to my profile (same profile, just a unique url  is given to you that is private to you only). So basically there are two ways or rather two urls to access my profile, a public url and a private url. It's kind of hard to explain why do i need to seperate the urls but just think that there's no other way if you're wondering.

The way i see this thing is through STI (single table inheritance) something like the following.

```
ProfileUrl < ActiveRecord::Base

PublicUrl < ProfileUrl
PrivateUrl < ProfileUrl

profile_url belongs_to :user
user has_one :profile_url

profile_url has_one :public_url
profile_url has_many :private_urls

private_url belongs_to :contact
contact has_one :private_url
```

i hope that makes sense, in a nutshell the story revolves around the profile of the user and ways to access that profile (public url for the world and private url specific to contacts of that user only, each contact will have a unique private url to the same profile of the user the contact belongs to). The profile table has a type, user_id, contact_id, url fields. I don't know if that's the best way to handle this situation but it would be great if you could help me in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `user has_many :contacts, :through=> :user_contacts` it seems to me that `user_contacts` is the best place to store private url for each contact in the user's contact list. And public url should probably be stored in `users` table (one per user).